# Firefox add-on sdk sidebar incompatibility - How do I warn the user?

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created an add-on with the add-on sdk. My add-on uses the ui/sidebar module. If a user installs my add-on with an older version of Firefox, such as Firefox ESR 24.1.1, the browser will inform the user that the add-on has been successfully installed. But, the add-on actually produces the following error (visible in the browser console):

```
Error: Module `sdk/ui/sidebar` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/ui/sidebar.js
resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js 133
```

This makes sense because I have read that the sidebar module was introduced with version 26. My understanding is that the add-on installs despite this because of the "Compatible By Default" functionality of the browser.

However, I find this behavior very undesirable for my add-on. Without knowing to look at the console, users will have no idea that the installation failed. What is the best practice for informing users about add-on incompatibilities? Is there a way to enforce the minVersion? Should I put a try block around the sidebar require statement and try to throw some sort of alert at the users informing them of the incompatibility?

Is there a standard way to address this? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
The minVersion had been set to 21.0 all along.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Firefox_Compatibility) on the MDN led me to think that the latest version of the SDK corresponded with the current version of Firefox (27 at the time). But, it looks like a new version of the SDK hasn't been released in quite some time. I'm on version 1.15 (which I downloaded from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation)). Since 1.15 was released a while ago, the current version of Firefox at that time was 21.0, and therefore the minVersion was set to 21.0. I failed to check it before posting, so I was under the impression that the add-on was being installed on Firefox 24 when the minVersion was 27.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an add-on to AMO, one of the things you have to tell about your add-on is the compatibility with Firefox (or SeaMonkey or Fenec):

[image]

Besides that, you may edit install.rdf file inside your-addon.xpi (notice it's a zip file) the following lines:

```
<!-- Firefox -->
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>21.0</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>25.0a1</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

That lines will be checked by Firefox when you as user try to install an addon (ie, .xpi file).

What you must do is properly set min and max versions in order to avoid incompatible browsers to install your add-on.

Comment: matagus is right. For a list of accepted version numbers see here: [Valid Application Versions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/appversions/)

Comment: Ah, I feel silly now. I hadn't actually checked the minVersion in the install.rdf file because [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Firefox_Compatibility) on the MDN said that "the minVersion is set to the currently shipping Firefox". Thus, I assumed that Firefox was ignoring the minVersion. But, it turns out it was set to 21.0, hence my problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Pwnosaurus you're welcome. If my answer was useful please vote it up and mark it as valid: this way we keep building stackoverflow content.

Comment: @matagus I modified the minVersion in install.rdf by unziping the xpi, changing the file, and then rezipping. However, I now get an error after installing. Firefox says that the add-on has been installed successfully, but the following error appears in the browser console.`"Error opening input stream (invalid filename?)" runner.js:162 \n
"Error opening input stream (invalid filename?)" promise.js:133` Any idea why? p.s. Should I open this as a new question?

Comment: Also it might be worth noting that I'm not currently using the AMO, just installing the `.xpi` manually.

Comment: As I said in my answer, setting minVersion and maxVersion makes Firefox to avoid installing add-ons which version si lower than or highest than those values, respectively. It doesn't make sense to let you install the add-on and then warn you that "it's incompatible".

Comment: About the error, check install.rdf to be a valud xml. That error occurs when the sdk can't load a filename because you change its name or it has invalid chars or a syntax error.